# TeeChart Smoothing

Tags: .net, teechart

i'm using a teecharts for .NET Fastline series, and then i'm drawing some simple plot, (for test i used)

```
        for (t = 0; t < maxPoints; ++t)
        {
            realtimeLine.Add(t, Math.Sin(t * 2 * Math.PI / 10 / 20));
        }
```

but then the amoount of points( maxPoints ) is big( 12000 ), the plot doesn't look well, there are omething like stairs on it(Stairs property is turned to false).

i also tried to use Line, with Smoothed = true, but in this case absolutely nothing happened, the plot haven't been drawn, in case if Smoothed =false, the plot draws but processor loading increases, comparatively to fast, that is not well for me, and i think, that smoothing also nedds some resources.

what should i do to get a smooth plot with fast line? I can send You my project, if you'll how can i do it

Answer (score 0):

In your case, I think would be very useful use the function Smoothing and apply it to your Fastline as do in next sample code:

```
public Form1()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
      InitializeChart();
    }
    const int maxPoints = 500;
    Steema.TeeChart.Styles.FastLine fast;
    Steema.TeeChart.Styles.FastLine fast1;
    Steema.TeeChart.Functions.Smoothing smoothing; 
    private void InitializeChart()
    {
      tChart1.Aspect.View3D = false; 
      fast = new FastLine(tChart1.Chart);
      fast1 = new FastLine(tChart1.Chart);
      smoothing = new Steema.TeeChart.Functions.Smoothing(); 
      for (int t = 0; t < maxPoints; ++t)
      {
        fast.Add(t, Math.Sin(t * 2 * Math.PI / 10 / 20));
      }
      fast1.DataSource = fast;
      fast1.Function = smoothing;
      smoothing.Period = 4;
      fast.Active = false; 
      checkBox1.Checked = true; 
    }
```

Could you tell us if previous code help you to achieve as you want?

I hope will helps.

Thanks,

Comment: Hi Sandra, thanks for your response, but unfortunately that didn't help. setting smoothing mode to antialiasing, i found that it looks like that antialiasing uses only integer points, not double, so finaly it looks like consequense of vertical lines, that's not looks good. partialy, the problems solves by using rounded endings, but that's not satisfiable. So probably you can tell me how make drawing quality better?

Comment: I have another question, is situation same in teechartAX? or, because of direct using gdi, the situation can be better?

Comment: Hello @user2519784, Ok, Is possible you have DrawAllPoints property set to false? If you want draw all points of FastLine series, the property DrawAllPoints must set true.Can you check it? 
On the other hand, if your problem persist, I would be very grateful if you can send us your project, because we can reproduce exactly your problem and try to suggest a good solution for you.  You can send us an e-mail to  "info at steema dot com" addressed to Sandra Pazos.  

Thanks,

Comment: Hello Sandra, i sent you a project two days agom with discription. Is there any progres?

Comment: Hello @user2519784, I inform you I have answered your question in e-mail you send me. As you will read in the e-mail, your problem is produced for the line of code you use in the  AfterDraw event (g.SmoothingMode = drawingMode; ). You must know that isn't correct use g.SmoothingMode in the afterdraw event. If you remove this line of code, your problem is solved. Thanks,